# Already used Linq query does not work in the different class in Enity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, linq, entity-framework

There are three functions in every partial class c (add,update,delete) which is made across every Database Table . I have wrote same kind of queries for two tables but when i came to third table .it shows an Exception .
My question is why is that so?

For example this query works fine

```
var result = (context.Customer.Count(c => c.CustomerCNIC == CNIC2));
```

but this query gives exception

```
var result = (context.Member.Count(c => c._MemberCNIC == CNIC2));
```

**Exception Details**

```
**Not Supported Exception was unhandled by user code**

 The specified type member '_MemberCNIC' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

Kindly help me .I dont even know the problem

**MemberCNIC TYPE:**

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
public global::System.String MemberCNIC
{
    get
    {
        return _MemberCNIC;
    }
    set
    {
        OnMemberCNICChanging(value);
        ReportPropertyChanging("MemberCNIC");
        _MemberCNIC = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
        ReportPropertyChanged("MemberCNIC");
        OnMemberCNICChanged();
    }
}

private global::System.String _MemberCNIC;
```

**CustomerCNIC Type**

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
public global::System.String CustomerCNIC
{
    get
    {
        return _CustomerCNIC;
    }
    set
    {
        OnCustomerCNICChanging(value);
        ReportPropertyChanging("CustomerCNIC");
        _CustomerCNIC = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
        ReportPropertyChanged("CustomerCNIC");
        OnCustomerCNICChanged();
    }
}

private global::System.String _CustomerCNIC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that _ character making the problem???? remove that under score from your table field and try to compile code as MemberCNIC...  Sorry if it doesnt help you as i'm not an expert in this LINQ

Comment: it works fine ._ was creating problem .but stil,i  don't understand the problem

Comment: because `_CustomerCNIC` is private

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `CustomerCNIC` is a property while `_MemberCNIC` is a data member.
[I'm only going on the standard of marking data members with an underscore]

Comment: And my guess was right. _MemberCNIC is a data member. And like the error says "Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties" are supported.